# *ngFor gives me 3 empty listed items, I dont know why and how to fix

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to display buttons, original idea is from the hero project, from angular:

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2

I get the list, but there are 3 empty listed item at the beginning, I tried the slice for the `*ngFor` to check to start it from item 2, but it is not helped, it just cut the original list, so still have the 3 empty item at the beginning of the list.

My issue:

[image: A screenshot of a navigation bar showing three empty spaces marked highlighted by a red box]

My html template:

```html
<div class="filter-row32">
  <ul class="categories">
    <li *ngFor="let category of categories">
      <button [class.selected]="category === selectedCategory" type="button" (click)="onSelect(category)">
        <img src={{category.image}} alt={{category.name}}><br> 
        <div class="overlay">
          <span class="name">{{category.name}}</span>
        </div> 
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
    
  <div *ngIf="selectedCategory">
    <h2>{{selectedCategory.name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
    <div>id: {{selectedCategory.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label for="category-name">Category name: </label>
      <input id="category-name" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The mock .ts:

```js
import { Category } from "./filter.component";
        
export const CATEGORIES: Category[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Flat' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/Flat-6C6C6C.png'},
  { id: 2, name: 'House' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/House-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Land' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/soil-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Garage' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/garage-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Holiday House' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/beach-house-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Office' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/office-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Shop' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/shop-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Restaurant' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/restaurant-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Storage' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/storage-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Industrial' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/industrial-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 11, name: 'Aggricultural' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/agricultural-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Development Area' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/headspace-area-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Lake'  , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/lake-6C6C6C.png'},
  { id: 14, name: 'Leisure Sport' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/sport-6C6C6C.png' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Institute' , image: 'assets/images/web/categories/institution-6C6C6C.png' },
];
```

The component ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';
import {FloatLabelType} from '@angular/material/form-field';
// For mock categories
import { CATEGORIES } from './mock-categories';
// import { Category } from './category';

/** Error when invalid control is dirty, touched, or submitted. */
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})

export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {
  hideRequiredControl = new FormControl(false);
  floatLabelControl = new FormControl('sale' as FloatLabelType);
  options = this._formBuilder.group({
    hideRequired: this.hideRequiredControl,
    floatLabel: this.floatLabelControl,
  });

  emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);

  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
  
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  getFloatLabelValue(): FloatLabelType {
    return this.floatLabelControl.value || 'auto';
  }

  // For mock categories
  categories = CATEGORIES;
  selectedCategory?: Category;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  } 

  onSelect(category: Category): void {
    this.selectedCategory = category;
  }

}

// For mock categories
export class Category {
  id!: number;
  name!: string;
  image!: string;
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up that `<img src={{category.image}} alt={{category.name}}><br>` should be `<img src="{{category.image}}" alt="{{category.name}}"><br>` - you need to wrap the string interpolation in double quotes for the template to be valid.

Comment: If I comment out the button, then the list appears well, so something around button function is fishy.                                                                   
 
        <li *ngFor="let category of categories">
          <!-- <button [class.selected]="category === selectedCategory" type="button" (click)="onSelect(category)"> -->
            <img src="{{category.image}}" alt="{{category.name}}"> 
            <div class="overlay">
              <span class="name">{{category.name}}</span>
            </div> 
          <!-- </button> -->
        </li>